# UIView not remembering its tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

Am I using the `UIView` `tag` property incorrectly? Why won't it remember its tag? [image]

When I check it in the debugger it says its value is `nil`.

Comment: po means 'print object'. Use 'p' instead to print an integer. It would also help to know how 'cellFront' is defined (i.e. is cellFront actually nil?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like either `cell` or `cell.cellFront` is nil.

Are you using `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` before dequeuing a cell? If not, you need to check if `cell` is `nil` and then create a new one if necessary.

When using `lldb` to check the tag, make sure you print the value with `p` (used for primitive types) instead of `po` (used for objects):

```
 (lldb) p cell.cellFront.tag
```

Comment: I'm using the storyboard before dequeuing.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `cell.cellFront` is `nil`?